# Updating the database - MVC3, Entity framework 4.1

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have an application that uses a database with one table currently. I want to add another column to the table. According to this post(http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part7-cs), there are 2 ways to modify the database: 1. Have EF drop and recreate the db or 2. Explicitly modify the db. Unfortunately, they go over the first method.

What is the correct / easiest way to do the second method if I have a table called Team?

The columns I have are TeamID, TeamAbbreviation, TeamCity, TeamName and TeamDisplayName. I want to add TeamSmallLogoUrl.

Answer (score 0):

To do the second method, just go modify the DB and add your column.  Then open the EDMX file in VS (double-click it in the Solution Explorer) and right-click on it when it opens up then choose "Update Model from Database" from the context menu.  Click Finish.  It'll pick up your added column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using code-first (hence the EF-4.1 title):

If you are still in development phase and there are no important data in the database, use the Drop-Recreate method. (this is also the easiest way).

If you have some data in the database, just do this manually. The names of the properties and class should match/map directly unto your database schema. (if not mapped, EF will throw an error anyways)

Comment: So if my class is Team.cs and like this:
public class Team
    {
        public int TeamID { get; set; }
        public string TeamAbbreviation { get; set; }
        public string TeamCity { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public string TeamDisplayName { get; set; }
        public string TeamSmallLogoUrl { get; set; }
    }

I manually added table column in the server explorer in VS 2010 and then put some string data in it. I rebuilt the solution and it still comes up with an error: The model backing ... context has changed since the database was created...